# Avoiding execution security alert in lotus notes

Tags: lotus

I created a button for polling in notes email body and then send it to a group of members for their voting. When the users, vote they get a execution security alert for each action the script. The following is the code placed in the **Yes** button.

```
Dim session As New notessession
Dim ws As New notesuiworkspace
Dim db As notesdatabase
Dim doc_poll As NotesDocument
Set db = session.getDatabase("Server Name", "ApplicationTesting/Polling.nsf")

Set doc_poll = db.CreateDocument()

Dim uidoc As NotesUIDocument

Set uidoc = ws.CurrentDocument


Dim doc As notesdocument
Set doc = uidoc.Document
If doc.temp(0) <> "yes" Then
    v_val=  ws.Prompt(3,"Family member count","No of Members ?")
    Call doc.ReplaceItemValue("temp","yes")
    Call doc.Save(True,True)
    Call doc.Sign
    Call doc.Save(True,True)
    doc_poll.Form = "Fo-PollReport"
    Call doc_poll.ReplaceItemValue("etxtUserName", session.CommonUserName   )

    Call doc_poll.ReplaceItemValue("etxtMembers", Cint(v_val))
    Call doc_poll.save(True,False)

    Messagebox"Your voting has been sent to HR", 64,"Voting"
Else
    Messagebox  "Your voting is already been sent to HR. Please contact HR directly,in case of any change in voting ",16, "Voting"
End If
```

How do i avoid execution security alert ?

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the ECL alerts the signature that the code is signed under would need to be on their ECL list and allow the related commands that are hitting the alerts.

You could push that signature down via a policy (security settings IIRC).

Comment: could you explain where do i set in the security setting IIRC

Comment: Main docs are here. http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.help.domino.admin.doc/DOC/H_INITIAL_ADMINISTRATION_ECL.html . Also check the admin ECL subsection in the docs, as this explains the policy end.